# Difference between dispatcher-servlet and spring-servlet

Tags: spring, spring-3

As the title says what is the difference between dispatcher-servlet.xml and spring-servlet.xml They seem very similar in terms of structure. When should one be used over the other ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an explanation from [spring forums](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?114430-Differnce-between-dispatcher-servlet-xml-and-spring-servlet-xml)

Basically it's just the name. Dispather is autoloading context called [servletname]-servlet.xml so in this case there's a servlet called 'spring' and another called 'dispatcher'.

You name your servlets in `web.xml`.

For example if you had:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>babubiba</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet </servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

in your `web.xml` then DispatcherServlet would try to load `babubiba-servlet.xml` by default.

If you can change context name by adding `contextConfigLocation` init-param to your servlet config.

Comment: But the spring framework knows to look for file dispatcher-servlet.xml ? because if I rename dispatcher-servlet.xml to spring-servlet.xml I receive exception - org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]

Comment: the <servlet-name> parameter in your web.xml names the servlet